# database for personal data and setting in android sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am currently developing a health app on android.
There would be a need to store personal data like gender, height and settings for app.
I plan to create a table with different columns.

My question is about creating the table with default values and editing the database.

My first thought is to create table and add a row with default values in `onCreate()`.
But it seems to be wrong usage of `onCreate()` as i see multiple examples that only `db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES)` is `onCreate()`.
Second thought is to make use of `DEFAULT` in SQL but still i have to find somewhere to run add row.
What's the good practice to do so?

About editing those data, i put multiple public get and set function in `sqliteopenhelper` class.
Is it right to do so?
As multiple tables are created, the `sqliteopenhelper` class seems to be a bit messy since there are a lot of functions.

Welcome to any suggestions and criticism.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your data really need an entire SQL Database? From your question I understand that you store data  (gender, height) for a single user. If it so, you can use Android's [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#GetSharedPreferences). SharedPreferences are a simple Key-Value store system where you have functions for both setting and getting you values based on a key (similar to a single SQL Table with two columns,  key and value).

Comment: You, no need for a database. SharedPreferences is really the choice. That make me realize I am so new to android